# Simplify jar version name in gradle?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

How can I have a simple version in my build jars in gradle? I have a jar like name-version-yyyyMMdd.time-iteration-classifier.jar - something like this. Is there a way to NOT have this `yyyyMMdd.time-iteration`. I use `maven-publish` plugin.

Comment: That `yyyyMMdd.time-iteration-classifier` stuff is non-standard.  You must already be using a plugin/logic that's explicitly adding it somewhere.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:version

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention an important detail. I see this version when `maven-publish` plugin executes